# Star Wars set identification 1

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I recently bought a big box of LEGO that have some broken LEGO Star Wars sets and I need help identifying them. Some are fairly complete and some are just pieces. The first 2 are almost complete so it should not be too hard to identify. For the rest, I pulled out the pieces that I thought would be easiest to identify and will post them in separate questions. Thanks for any help you can provide! [image: looks to be a republic ship]

This one appears to be a Wookiee ship.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the [7674-1 V-19 Torrent](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7674-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
[image]

And the second one is [7752-1 Count Dooku's Solar Sailer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7752-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
[image]